# Added duplicate data are ovewritten in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, overwrite

So I have this function `addToCart` in `Javascript` where by clicking on a button the name of the item and Amount is saved to `LocalStorage` and then I get the data with `innerHTML`. The problem here is that whenever I click twice or more times on that button the data overwrites.

For example I want to add one doll to cart, then I want to add another two dolls, then saved is only>

> Doll:2

but i want it to be

> Doll:1 
>  Doll:2

My code:

```
const lookUpItem = matches.map((match, idx)=>
    `<h2 id="name"><span id="${match.itemName}">${match.itemName}</span></h2>
     <p>Amount: <span id="am_${idx}">${match.amount1}</span></p>
     <button onclick="addToCart('${match.itemName}', 'am_${idx}')" id="add">Add to Cart</button>
                    </span></small>
            </div>`
        ).join('');
        itemList.innerHTML = lookUpItem;

//outPut is id of an <ul> in HTML
const outPutHTML = document.getElementById("outPut");

//nm, am - variables from array.map
//saves line to localStorage and adds line to outputHTML
function addToCart(nm, am) {
    {
        const itemName = nm;
        const amount = document.getElementById(am).innerText;
        localStorage.setItem(itemName, amount);
        outPutHTML.innerHTML += `${itemName}: ${amount}<br />`;
    }
}

//shows all data in Local Storage in outPutHTML
for(let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    const name = localStorage.key(i);
    const value = localStorage.getItem(name);
    outPutHTML.innerHTML += `${name}: ${value} <br />`;
}
```

How to solve this, I saw that you could solve this with `JSON.stringtify`, but don't exactly know how to apply it? I appreciate the help.

Comment: `localStorage.key` already hints that you store with a key. A key is unique. You cannot have two entries with the same key. You need to abandon this way of working. For instance, keep track of the information in an array, and store the array in local storage.

Comment: As per @trincot and also if you want to increase the count of an already existing item, then you need logic in place (which don't have) to see if the item is already in the cart, so to increment the quanity. You would likely want to do this in your `addToCart` function.

Comment: Really all he needs is to say `localStorage.setItem("name of item",localStorage.getItem("name of item") + "any value");` am I not mistaken?

Comment: You are not entirely mistaken @OOPSStudio, but suppose the key doesn't exist yet. And being that the payload is a string, `+` will concatenate.

Comment: He could have a simple check for `if(localStorage.getItem("name of item") !== null)` to make sure that the item already exists. And as for the "+ will concatenate", yes... That's entirely the point. He wants "Doll: 2" to appear after "Doll: 1", he doesn't want to increment the value by one........ He wants to concatenate.

Comment: I see your point @OOPSStudio. But that still doesn't handle the issue of unique keys in the local storage. He cant have two keys named "Doll". .... trincot mentions the unique key situation already in comments.

Comment: . . . But by calling `localStorage.setItem("name of item","value")`, he's just overwriting the old value with the old value + the new value... I don't see the issue? Do you mean that by calling `localStorage.setItem()` on a key that already exists you'll get an error? If so, I am mistaken, but I don't believe that's the case and my solution should work just fine, no?

Comment: @trincot what should be used instead of key, also the information are fetched from API, so I just took values from it and put them into array map

Comment: @GetSet here, run these commands in your dev console: `localStorage.setItem("banana","something");` - `localStorage.getItem("banana");` - `localStorage.setItem("banana",localStorage.getItem("banana") + ", something else");` - `localStorage.getItem("banana");`     ---     You'll see that this works perfectly fine...

Comment: Will try it @OOPSStudio

Comment: @OOPSStudio just by setting the Item, the data still overwrites, e.g. i put 1 doll and if i add another two dolls i just see 2 dolls in my localstorage, but I want to see all two entries for statistics,

Comment: For reference on @OOPSStudio approach, I get `something, something else` for `banana` key in local storage. That's a bit different from what OP wants which is impossible because keys have to be unique. That is OP seems to want duplicate keys with different values; that can't happen.

Comment: Hm. I must be misunderstanding something then, sorry. The way I see it, being able to collect the value from a key, append data onto that value, and write it back into the key... Is exactly what OP wants? If that's not the case (and it may not be) then I'm very mistaken... But I have been assuming all along that that was the case.

Comment: Yeah, on face value I see the misunderstanding @OOPSStudio. But what really what OP needs is to update the cart count for the *same* item, and thus the same key.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks for explaining. Sorry for misunderstanding in the first place though! I think the part of OP's post where he says "then the save is only `Doll: 2` but I want it to be `Doll: 1Doll: 2`" is the part that confuses me. It appears that he wants both values to be saved into the same key, but apparently that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store two items with the same key in local storage.

It is better to first think how you would store it in memory -- without the locale storage in mind.

For instance, you could imagine this structure:

```
items = [
    { name: "Doll", value: "1" },
    { name: "Doll", value: "2" }
];
```

And if you need to add another, you just do

```
items.push({ name: "Doll", value: "15" });
```

And once you have your memory structure defined, you can just write that whole structure to local storage, using *one*, hard-coded key:

```
localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
```

And to read that information at the start of your page:

```
items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items") || "[]");
```

The `||` is there to treat the case where the data is not yet present in local storage, in which case you want to get an empty array.

So here is part of your code adapted. The comments are your comments, so you can see where the code fits in:

```
//shows all data in Local Storage in outPutHTML
const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items") || "[]");
outPutHTML.innerHTML = items.map(({name, value}) => `${name}: ${value}<br>`)
                            .join("");

//saves line to localStorage and adds line to outputHTML
function addToCart(name, am) {
    const value = document.getElementById(am).innerText;
    items.push({name, value});
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
    outPutHTML.innerHTML += `${name}: ${value}<br>`;
}
```

Comment: "You cannot store two items with the same key in local storage." You can if you simply convert them to strings, concatenate them, save that string into the key, and then `.split()` it later on, no? I don't see why the solution needs to be made complex when really the underlying solution is to just store multiple values in one key... Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: My point is that you cannot store data as two local storage entries, where each entry has the same key. Of course, you can store any string linked to one key, and that string can have all the complexity you want (which is also what this answer proposes). But that was not my point. My answer is not overly complex. It just uses `JSON` encoding instead of a comma delimiter, which is more reliable when you want to store strings that have a comma.

Comment: its show a syntaxerror for the JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data and i put the same line, im getting the data into an array map

Comment: That means you didn't write the data to local storage in JSON format. I see that I first mentioned the right code for that, but then didn't do the stringification in the final code block. I have done this now.

Comment: Thanks, I've use the join method to convert items into string, with stringify HTML output showed unnecessary commas behind each line

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the right way to do it.